# Confusing apache's server-status

Tags: apache2

I have a CentOS 5.5 Final with Apache 2.2.3... I was checking about possible misconfigurations or similar so I settled the server-status which reports to me this result just opening only the page of server-status:

```
Apache Server Status for 192.168.3.23

Server Version: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Server Built: Aug 30 2010 12:32:08

Current Time: Tuesday, 07-Aug-2012 10:10:23 CEST
Restart Time: Tuesday, 07-Aug-2012 10:04:40 CEST
Parent Server Generation: 0
Server uptime: 5 minutes 42 seconds
Total accesses: 5 - Total Traffic: 19 kB
CPU Usage: u0 s0 cu0 cs0
.0146 requests/sec - 56 B/second - 3891 B/request
1 requests currently being processed, 7 idle workers

_____W__........................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................

Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process

Srv PID     Acc     M   CPU     SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client     VHost        Request
0-0 28511   0/1/1   _   0.00    248 0   0.0     0.00    0.00    X.X.X.X    127.0.0.1    GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
1-0 28512   0/1/1   _   0.00    238 0   0.0     0.00    0.00    X.X.X.X    127.0.0.1    GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
2-0 28513   0/1/1   _   0.00    225 0   0.0     0.00    0.00    X.X.X.X    127.0.0.1    GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
3-0 28515   0/1/1   _   0.00    218 0   0.0     0.00    0.00    X.X.X.X    127.0.0.1    GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
4-0 28516   0/1/1   _   0.00    7   0   0.0     0.00    0.00    X.X.X.X    127.0.0.1    GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
5-0 28517   0/0/0   W   0.00    0   0   0.0     0.00    0.00    X.X.X.X    127.0.0.1    GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
```

Since I am the only one who is looking at that page shouldn't that result just show only one row even if I refresh the page with CTRL+F5 on the browser? If yes do you think there could be some misconfigurations?

Comment: Better ask this over at http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Thanks thilo.... asked on serverfault :-)